# LINQ query to create a list of objects where each object contains a list

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML describing some data like this:

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Alice</Name>
        <Dogs>
            <Dog>Labrador</Dog>
            <Dog>German Shepherd</Dog>
        </Dogs>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Bob</Name>
        <Dogs>
            <Dog>Poodle</Dog>
        </Dogs>
    </Person>
</People>
```

And some classes:

```
class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

class Dogs
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use linq to XML to query this data, so that I can create a set of Person objects with the Dog collection for each populated. How do I do this? Something like:

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");
 var enumerableOfPeople = from u in doc.Root.Descendants("Person")
                    select new Person() { Name = u.Element("Name").Value,
                                          Dogs = /* WHAT GOES HERE */ };
```

Comment: are you sure your class it's correct with your code?

Comment: I wrote the code above in the stackoverflow editors so there may be some minor mistakes but i think it gives the general idea .. which bit is incorrect let me know and i'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will populate the Dogs:

```
var enumerableOfPeople = from u in doc.Root.Descendants("Person")
                         select new Person()
                         {
                               Name = u.Element("Name").Value,
                               Dogs = (from d in u.Element("Dogs").Descendants("Dog")
                                       select new Dog() { Type = d.Value }).ToList()
                         };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var enumerableOfPeople = doc.Root.Descendants("Person")
                        .Select(u => new Person { 
                            Name = u.Element("Name").Value, 
                            Dogs = u.Descendants().Select(x => new Dog{ Type = x.Value}).ToList() 
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

A `lambda` approach to getting the people:

```
var peeps = doc.Root.Descendants("Person").Select(r => new Person()
{
    Name = r.Element("Name").Value,
    Dogs = r.Element("Dogs").Descendants("Dog").Select(t => new Dog()
    {
        Type = t.Value
    }).ToList()
});
```

Comment: OP used LINQ, too. You are using LAMBDA syntax

Comment: Both is Part of linq